# MinGW, always linking with pthreads

Tags: c, windows, pthreads, mingw, ld

I've recently been trying to use MinGW for my development purposes, but there have been a few issues.

It seems it always wants to link with pthread for some reason.
I tried compiling a simple hello world in C and got an error like

> ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread

Obviously it is searching for the pthread library and not finding it. I downloaded the library from MinGW-get, and as expected, the compilation and linking worked.

However, after stripping the executable for a simple hello world in C which only includes stdio.h, the file was still 46k large.
The same file compiled and stripped with gcc on Cygwin is like 9k, and MSVC is also similar.

So it was complaining about a library missing.
Providing the library fixed the problem and made it work.
But a stripped hello world in C is still 46k, while with gcc on cygwin it's 9k.

The natural thing to conclude is that MinGW is using the pthread library for some reason.

But I cannot find a way to disable MinGW wanting to link with pthread anywhere. Ironically everything I found on google is people having trouble getting pthread to work with MinGW.

Is there any way to make MinGW *not* want to link with pthread?

Comment: How do you build your app? Is it as just `gcc hello.c`?

Comment: @KirillDaybov Yes, I just run `gcc hello.c` and then `strip a.exe` . I find it peculiar that it was complaining about the pthread library when I just invoked it without any arguments, and it was also a fresh install.

Comment: it looks like mingw just doesn't work without pthread. I found [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154186/why-does-c-hello-world-require-pthread-which-is-missing-in-eclipse-mars) with the same problem. He decided that it was an installation problem.

Comment: it works for me using MinGW-w64.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - fetched a fresh copy of mingw, compiled/stripped `hello.c`. It's not linked to anything, just `kernel32` and `msvcrt`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities when installing MinGW-W64 on windows.
I am betting that you installed it for posix threads and not win32.
Run the setup again and use the compiler from the newly created directory.

[image: MinGW Setup Screen]

Comment: I just tried the latest installer from https://www.msys2.org/ ([msys2-x86_64-20210725.exe](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/download/2021-07-25/msys2-x86_64-20210725.exe)), and I was specifically looking for these Settings, and I couldn't find them?! Is it still possible to access these?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstallation of SDL2 avoiding binary conflict between SDL files and SDL2 files will resolve the immediate problem.

To solve the new problem would need to go the SDL2 distribution file (the one copied to MinGW) and copy the SDL2.dll from it [DLL from distributable][1]--- by dragging the file over your debug and/or release folders where the .exe file lives.(.exe + dll -> right?) moving dll to exes. Build/Run the program it should work! You should see a Welcome message! https://www.caveofprogramming.com/c-for-complete-beginners/setting-up-sdl-windows.html